# Admin Backend of Joomla (ADMIN PANEL) is extremely slow

Tags: php, joomla

Hello i have problem with Joomla 1.5.26

The front end of the website is opening fast. But admin panel loading extremely slow and from one link to other it takes ~1 minute to load!

Hosting providers tells me that there is no problems in our hosting and server where are hosted our websites.

Here is php.ini file that my hosting providers put into main folder of website https://www.dropbox.com/s/djuinnmdjftsi1r/php.ini

This is because yesterday i cannot login in the system and shows me message: Internal Server Error 500. Now works fine but load time is killing me..

What to do?

Comment: Rather hard to say to be honest. Are you using a 3rd party template for the backend? Do you have any extra scripts being loaded there?

Comment: Website is 3 years old and problem apper when 5 days ago i change main password for admin user. Front end loading fast as usual. We have other Joomla website, same version, and i change main admin password also but there is no problem like this one...

Comment: Any (statistics) plugins that might slow it down?

Comment: We use google analitycs.

Comment: The only change you made was to change the user password? What version of PHP are you on? You might want to turn error reporting on to see if you are throwing any notices. 1.5 really has a lot of php 4 code that is going to throw notices all over the place.

Comment: I turn on Debug option in admin panel and there is information:

Application afterLoad: 0.003 seconds, 1.01 MB
Application afterInitialise: 0.137 seconds, 8.74 MB
Application afterRoute: 0.139 seconds, 8.93 MB
Application afterDispatch: 0.165 seconds, 10.34 MB
Application afterRender: 60.259 seconds, 11.12 MB

Comment: Go to the server tab and turn error reporting to development. Just do this for a minute because you don't really want this showing on a live site.

Comment: I turn it off. What can i do now?

Comment: OK i figure it out. I delete all plugins and then backend work fine and fast! Just need to find which is the plugin that make this happen.

Comment: You deleted all plugins on your live site?

Comment: Update Manager - Webconstruction.ch

This basturd is responsable for slow backend. Just you know.

Comment: I met the same problem. I have several extensions. I suspect the Joomla update system to slow down the administrator login. When logging in Joomla, it search updates for installed extensions. As each extension uses its own update server I think some servers responses slowly and it slows down the login process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As provided in the comments against the original question, answering the "What to do?" question.

- Turn error reporting to Development and review the errors/warning/notices, then revert error reporting back to the previous setting
- Turn on debugging and inspect the load time of the various phases
- Disable all additional extensions, then re-enable one by one, or variations on this approach
- Update extensions to latest versions (though you really want to do this on a test site first)
- Clone the site and try and reproduce the problem, then you have somewhere to do more aggressive debugging without effecting your end users

Aside: I had a similar problem recently with a NoNumber extension and it turned out a regex was performing poorly.  I had upgraded the extension which upgraded the framework, which effected another extension from the same provider.  The solution was upgrading all extensions from that provider.  Or... perhaps I have this wrong and that was an unrelated problem.  I had another where I had applied an update which contained the problem.  By the time I got around to debugging, the developer had already provided a fix - I just had to go looking.

Comment: Update Manager - Webconstruction.ch

This basturd is responsable for slow backend. Just you know.

Answer (score 0):

Would advice to set error reporting to 'maximum' instead of 'development'. Consider 'development' to verbose due to 'strict' messages.